# Qlik View 9 versioning Git

Tags: git, qlikview

I'm trying to version my QlikView 9 app. So I should create a folder with the same name as .qvw file I intend to version adding `-prj` suffix.

My app name is `app.qvw`. In the same folder a new folder `app-prj` is created. When I save the app normally `app-prj` should be populated with XML files but it is not the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried to close, open and then save?

Comment: Is there not even the .log file? That usually tells you what failed. Also is there a particular reason you can't use the latest version of QV?

Comment: nothing at all, was it already implemented in QV 9?

Comment: Version control was only introduced in QlikView 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the latest version of Qlikview, if possible.
AFAIR they introduced this feature with version 11.

Comment: no possibility to use the latest version :) is there any other way to version my QV9 app?

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic option for your approach. 
I can only imagine a solution via your workflow.
For example, handling your script in an external qvs file, which you could include to your QVW. This file can be easily added to git.  
Other option would be to always manually export your whole script and manually add it to git.

Comment: Thanks for answer